# mssql - when /how to use table variables

Tags: php, sql-server, variables, in-memory

I am scripting in PHP and using a MsSQL database.

My script loops though a list of product ids.  For each id it creates an object of product data. For the 'postage' field within the product object I call a postage class that performs another query.

```
$products = $productsObj->getProducts($i, $limit);

foreach($products as $product)
{

echo $product['productName'] . '|';
echo $product['productDescription'] . '|';
echo $product['productPrice'] . '|';

$postage = $postageObj->getPostageCostforProduct(1, $product['weight'], $product['productPrice']);

echo $postage . '|';

}
```

I have been told that I could possibly make use of 'table variables' to speed up this process in the event of lots of products.  However, I am struggling to understand how this can help and how to implement this.  Would I replace my existing postage query in the postage class with a table variable query? If so, exactly how does this work and help server load?

**EDIT**

The query to get a list of product IDs is:

```
SELECT * FROM  FROM products WHERE category='$this->cat'
```

I then loop through each of them and create and object for each product.  The query to get the products data for the object is:

```
SELECT  p.id as prod_id, * FROM products AS p WITH(NOLOCK)
WHERE (p.id = '$this->prod_id')
```

When displaying the data I call the following query to get the postage:

```
SELECT Postage.postageName, Postage.Description AS postagedesc, Postage.id, Postage.qtyPer, Postage.pricePer, Postage.groupID, Groups.country_filter FROM  Postage 
LEFT OUTER JOIN Groups ON Postage.groupID = Groups.id 
WHERE  (Postage.minimumQty <= '$qty') AND (PostageRules.maximumQty >= '$qty') 
 (Postage.minPrice <= '$price') AND (Postage.maxPrice >= '$price')
```

Comment: You are not alone, I fail to see the need for table variables in your case as well. What you may really need, though, is a single query returning products with their postage costs, so that you can avoid running multiple `getPostageCostforProduct` requests. I know PHP very little, but I might be able to help you with a SQL query if you elaborate more on what tables (on the server side) are involved, what their structures are and which column in which table references which column in the other table. (Maybe you could instead just post the two SQL queries used in this particular fragment.)

Comment: thank you that would be great.  sql added above.

Comment: I'm a bit confused, to be honest. As can be guessed from my last comment, I was under impression that only two queries were employed here. It's your second query that I can't really see being invoked in your code, but that, of course, may well be my poor knowledge/understanding of PHP speaking for itself. I've made my attempt at an answer, though, and if it's a complete rubbish, please do let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could retrieve the products along with their postage cost values in a single query, using an outer join to `Postage`:

```sql
SELECT
  pr.productName,
  pr.productDescription,
  pr.productPrice,
  pr.productWeight,
  po.postageName,
  po.Description AS postagedesc,
  po.id,
  po.qtyPer,
  po.pricePer,
  po.groupID,
  gr.country_filter
FROM products AS pr
  LEFT JOIN Postage AS po
    ON po.minimumQty <= pr.productWeight
   AND po.maximumQty >= pr.productWeight
   AND po.minPrice   <= pr.productPrice
   AND po.maxPrice   >= pr.productPrice
  LEFT JOIN Groups  AS gr
    ON po.groupID = gr.id
WHERE pr.category = '$this->cat'
```

I guess, this query could be defined under a different name in `productsObj` (say, as `getProductsWithPostageCosts`) and used, perhaps, like this:

```
$products = $productsObj->getProductsWithPostageCosts($i, $limit);

foreach($products as $product)
{

echo $product['productName'] . '|';
echo $product['productDescription'] . '|';
echo $product['productPrice'] . '|';
echo $product['postageName'] . '|';
echo $product['postagedesc'] . '|';
...
echo $product['country_filter'] . '|';

}
```

Comment: yes this is a solution, however, it doesn't use table variables.  I was hoping to learn how to use table variables for this problem. But perhaps using table variables it not a solution for this scenario.

Comment: Like I said before, this particular problem doesn't seem to need table variables. A table variable is basically a temporary table, only, like any other variable, it's only visible to the (multi-statement) query where it's declared. If you know how to work with actual T-SQL temp tables (`#`- and `##`- ones), I'm sure you'll learn table variables easily. You do not CREATE nor DROP them, just DECLARE them, and they are the only kind of temporary table that is allowed for use in T-SQL UDFs. Other than that, there's not much difference: you can SELECT FROM, INSERT INTO, UPDATE, or DELETE FROM them.